# How to remove the first 6 characters of all files in a folder that start with a certain criteria (ex.XXXX_job name.txt)?

Tags: python

******UPDATE*******

So here is my code I've written so far:

```
import os
import glob
import re
#from pathlib import Path
import sys

print("Welcome!")
path = r"D:\aerial_mbu\ForeFlight\ForeFlight Content Packs\OGLMissionsContentPack\layers"


files = os.listdir(path)
for name in files:
    if name.startswith("1"):
        new_name = name.replace(name[:6], "")
        print(new_name)
        os.rename(name, new_name)
```

Unfortunately it's not renaming the files, instead I keep getting the error seen below: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zE23C.png)

It looks like something is wrong with my os.rename call because it's printing the correct name (new_name)

******ORIGINAL POST*******
I'm looking for a way to rename some files in a folder. Some of the filenames start with 6 additional numbers and some don't. I would like to go through the whole folder and remove the 6 additional number from the files that have them.

Current folder ex:

```
1111_job_name1.txt
1112_job_name2.txt
1113_job_name3.txt
job_name4.txt
1115_job_name5.txt
job_name6.txt
```

Desired folder ex:

```
job_name1.txt
job_name2.txt
job_name3.txt
job_name4.txt
job_name5.txt
job_name6.txt
```

I had originally tried calling rename in the command line but I couldn't get it to work because of the conditionality.

Comment: post the code you have tried

Comment: If you're on Windows use https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Download.php

Answer (score 1):

here is a script I created  based on this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rename-multiple-files-using-python/)

```
# importing os module 
import os 

# Function to rename multiple files  def main(): 

    for  filename in enumerate(os.listdir("src/")): #src is the directory 
        dst =filename[5:]
        src = 'src/'+filename 
        dst = 'src/'+dst 

        # rename() function will 
        # rename all the files 
        os.rename(src, dst)    
# Driver Code  if __name__ == '__main__': 

    # Calling main() function 
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use re to match if the string has digits as 6 characters and if it doesn't it evaluates to NULL and statements inside if is not executed.It only matches with start as we use "^"

```
re.findall(r"^\d{6}",files). #here 6 denotes the number of digits it starts with
```

Then later  with

```
re.sub(r"^\d{6}","",files)
```

You can substitute those matched characters to `""` -> to an empty string.There by stripping.
So your code goes like this

```
import os
import re
for files in os.listdir():
    if(re.findall(r"^\d{6}",files)):
        os.rename(files,re.sub(r"^\d{6}","",files))
```

I see that there is an "_" if you want to strip that too you can use this 
`r"^\d{6}\_"` as the re expression.
If you don't want to enter the number of digits before hand and want to strip files that starts with any number of digits use this `r"^[0-9]+\_"`

Comment: Does this take into account the conditionality of the problem? This looks like it's the easiest solution but I don't know what the r"^\d{6}" does. Can you elaborate?

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.